# "I = [MxNx4]" meaning?

Tags: matlab

I am doing an image processing project.  In my project there is an GUI file that reads an image and processing it for segmentation. while reading an image file, initially it is checking the size of that image...  However, I don't understand what the function `I=[m x n x 4]`  really means.  Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: That's not a MATLAB command/function/etc.  Is that from comments?  If so, I'd say that just gives the dimensions of a variable `I`.

Answer (score 1):

Your image `I` is of size `m` pixels high by `n` pixels wide and has 4 channels: Red, Green, Blue and an [alpha channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing).
Matlab stores `I` as a 3D array, you can access the `x-y`-th pixel by `I(y,x,:)` returning the four-vector representing the RGBA value of the `x-y`-th pixel.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to transform it from m*n*4 to m*n*3. I'm having a hard time finding a way to make it work. @Shai

Comment: @Jonathan use `reshape` command